# How to get this console in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

How do I get the Chrome console to behave like the one in this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yiEeiMN2Khs
[image]

This is what mine is doing when I hit the return key:
[image]

My Chrome address bar has the following:

> chrome://blank

which is the same as the in the video.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Press <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd>.

This enters a line break and does not "submit" the line.

---

Note: This is quite typical for systems that would otherwise "submit" the content on enter, e.g. chat systems.

Comment: Is there a way to clear the error without completely clearing all your code if you accidentally hit <return> only at some point?

Comment: Just clear the console and press the up arrow (while in the input) to go through the input history.

Comment: Nice.  Thanks.  By the way, how did you get the keyboard graphics into your answer?

Comment: I find it's easier to write code in a text editor (notepad / sublime / etc) and then copy the code into the console. Then you don't have to worry about pressing shift+enter all the time

Comment: @4thSpace: Using the `<kbd>` tag: `<kbd>shift</kbd>`.

Comment: @jasonscript: Yeah, I believe Firefox also has a scatchpad for that (yep: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Scratchpad): *"Unlike the Web Console, which is designed for interpreting a single line of code at a time, Scratchpad lets you edit larger chunks of JavaScript code, then execute it in various ways depending on how you want to use the output."*